# uniform continuity, assignment

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I had this homework question:

> Assume that $f :[0, \infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly
>   continuous. Show that there exists constants A, B such that $|f(x)| \le Ax+B$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$.

I solved it my taking $B =|f(0)|$. And Since there exists a $\delta$, such that if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<1$. So I chose $A = \frac1{\delta}$.

The solution also had $A = \frac1{\delta}$, where $\delta$ was defined the same way. But it had that $B = |f(0)|+1$.

**Do we need the $+1$ on $B$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we need the $+1$: Consider $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Then for small $x > 0$, we have

$$f(x) > Ax$$

for every $A$, so we need to add something to $\lvert f(0)\rvert$ to get the inequality for small $x > 0$.